# How to calculate lambda.1se from iterative cross validation?

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I have the following code to choose a value of `lambda` based on the lowest resulting mean squared error (MSE) after iterated cross validation.

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(3)

IV1 <- data.frame(IV1 = rnorm(100))
IV2 <- data.frame(IV2 = rnorm(100))
IV3 <- data.frame(IV3 = rnorm(100))
IV4 <- data.frame(IV4 = rnorm(100))
IV5 <- data.frame(IV5 = rnorm(100))
DV <- data.frame(DV = rnorm(100))

data <- data.frame(IV1,IV2,IV3,IV4,IV5,DV)
x <- model.matrix(DV~.-IV5 , data)[ , -1]
y <- data$DV

AB <- glmnet(x=x, y=y, alpha=1)
plot(AB,xvar="lambda")

lambdas <- NULL
for (i in 1:100){
  fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y)
  errors <- data.frame(fit$lambda, fit$cvm)
  lambdas <- rbind(lambdas, errors)
}

lambdas <- aggregate(lambdas[ , 2], list(lambdas$fit.lambda), mean)


bestindex <- which(lambdas[2]== min(lambdas[2]))
bestlambda <- lambdas[bestindex,1]
```

How would I modify this to select `lambda.1se` (i.e., the largest λ at which the MSE is within one standard error of the minimal MSE)?

Edit:

How about this

```
    lambdas <- NULL #initialize
n.fits <- 100
for (i in 1:n.fits) {
    {
  fit <- cv.glmnet(x,y)
  errors = data.frame(fit$lambda,fit$cvm)
  lambdas <- rbind(lambdas,errors)
  r2[i]<-max(1-fit$cvm/var(y))
}
# take mean cvm for each lambda
lambdas <- aggregate(lambdas[, 2], list(lambdas$fit.lambda), mean)
lambdas<-as.data.frame(lambdas)

# find subset with mse within 1 se of mean
onese<-std.error(lambdas[2])
min<-min(lambdas[2])
low<-min-onese
high<-min+onese

lambdas<-subset(lambdas, x>low)
lambdas<-subset(lambdas, x<high)

#choose highest lambda among those

bestindex = which(lambdas[1]==max(lambdas[1]))
bestlambda = lambdas[bestindex,1]
```

Comment: Please include all `library` lines if methods are not base R or user-defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use `cv.glmnet`, the following might be what you are looking for. (p.s. I also cleaned up your simulation code a bit; note that I also didn't make use of the `AB` object from `glmnet` which is obviously not the same as `cv.glmnet`)

```
library(glmnet)

## Simulate data:
set.seed(3)
x <- data.frame(
  IV1 = rnorm(100),
  IV2 = rnorm(100),
  IV3 = rnorm(100),
  IV4 = rnorm(100),
  IV5 = rnorm(100)
)
x <- as.matrix(x)
y <- rnorm(100) #target or response

## Iteratively fit models
lambdas <- NULL #initialize
n.fits <- 100
for (i in 1:n.fits) {
  fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian")
  df <- data.frame(fit$lambda.1se, mean(fit$cvm) ) #can use median for CVM also
  lambdas <- rbind(lambdas, df)
}

## Select best lambda:
bestindex <- which.min(lambdas[ , 2]) #the way you had it was way too complicated
bestlambda <- lambdas[bestindex, 1]
bestlambda
```

Comment: Am I right that this finds lambda.1se for each iteration, and then from that distribution, chooses the one with the lowest mse? I had thought that I would find the mean mse for each value of lambda first, and then from that distribution, find the one that satisfies 1se. Does that make sense?

Comment: I figure what I can do is, using my code, do `bestindex = which(lambdas[1]==max(lambdas[1]))` but then I am unsure how to say "such that lambdas[2] is between minimum lambdas[2] +/- 1 standard error".